# How to have my Python Slack Bot monitor a room for a keyword and send a link to that message into another room?

Tags: python, chatbot, slack

I am at the point where my bot can join a room and reply when a user says something. However, I would like to have my bot join a slack room #room1 and monitor that room and threads for a variation of keywords (0 out of 20, 1 out of 20, 2 out of 20....up to 19 out of 20). Whenever those phrases are seen I would like the bot to send a link of that thread to another room where support staff is waiting #support and they can then take action. Here is my current code:

```
import slack
import os
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from flask import Flask
from slackeventsapi import SlackEventAdapter

env_path = Path('.') / '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)

app = Flask(__name__)
slack_event_adapter = SlackEventAdapter(
    os.environ['SIGNING_SECRET'], '/slack/events', app)

client = slack.WebClient(token=os.environ['SLACK_TOKEN'])
BOT_ID = client.api_call("auth.test")['user_id']

@slack_event_adapter.on('message')
def message(payload):
    event = payload.get('event', {})
    channel_id = event.get('channel')
    user_id = event.get('user')
    text = event.get('text')
   
    if BOT_ID != user_id:
        client.chat_postMessage(channel=channel_id, text=text)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```